# Insertion in HashMap not working properly

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am inserting a sorted object into a HashMap but its not getting sorted.

```
Map<Long, Object> sortedObject = new HashMap(Long, Object>();    
for(Object sortedObject : sortedObjectList)
    {
      sortedMap.put(sortedObject.getId(), sortedObject);
    }

    syso(new Gson().toJson(sortedMap);
```

In output I was expecting sorted map, but its random.
Please help.

Comment: HashMaps are not sorted. They store elements in an unpredictable order. Where did you get the idea that HashMaps are sorted?

Comment: Try using a `TreeMap` instead. That will come out sorted if you iterate over it, but not sure how `Gson` will handle it.

Comment: @musical_coder Gson is just to get output in more readable form. Nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: Uh...then what is your question exactly?

Comment: @immibis I am beginner in java. I was expecting it sorted because i was doing map.put. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[`Hashmap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is unordered. Use [`Treemap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to sort. Try this:

```
Map<Long, Object> sortedObject = new HashMap<Long, Object>(); 

for(Object sortedObject : sortedObjectList)
{
    sortedMap.put(sortedObject.getId(), sortedObject);
} 
System.out.println("Unsort Map......");
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(sortedMap);

System.out.println("Sorted Map......");
Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(sortedMap);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(treeMap);
```

TreeMap is an example of a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), which means that the order of the keys can be sorted, and when iterating over the keys, you can expect that they will be in order.

HashMap on the other hand, makes no such guarantee. Therefore, when iterating over the keys of a HashMap, you can't be sure what order they will be in.

HashMap will be more efficient in general, so use it whenever you don't care about the order of the keys.

`HashMap` is specified to be `O(1)`: 'constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets'. `TreeMap` is specified to 'guaranteed `log(n)` time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Go through Javadocs that I shared for more details.

Comment: Will TreeMap affect performance? (Comparing HashMap and TreeMap)

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not sorted, It stores in Key-Value pairs.
Values are mapped with the corresponding keys.